# How to prevent single quotes when using $this->db->escape in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have insert to columns with single quotes. As `$this->db->query` already takes care of all the special character. But my problem is i to insert data like **ganesh's** when the insertion takes place, only ganesh is inserted; data after the single quotes are missing. So i started using `$this->db->escape` but this adds single quotes to my data which is not required how to prevent this

my code

```
$sql="insert into tablename (list_name,list_address) values(?,?)" 
$res=this->db-query($sql,array($name,$add));
```

MY mistake was in front end. Not back end. I will delete the question.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: i tried using where_not_in where(not exists()) both didnt execute.. also i tried a suggestion using null,false in where in the end.. even that didnt work!

Comment: I added a field to 1st table,as a flag . So when i insert into the 2nd table i update the flag. this solves my problem,avoiding the complex query!

Comment: So are your saying you would like the data to be stored like `ganesh's` or like `ganeshs`?

Answer (score 5):

In cases of complex queries i find it easier to just send raw query like this :

```
$query = "your query";
$result = $this->db->query($query);
```

Don't forget to escape variables before inserting them to the query like this :

```
$var = $this->db->escape($var);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save the data with the single quote you will need to add slashes to the data before saving it to the database like this:

```
$sql="insert into tablename (list_name,list_address) values(?,?)";
$res=this->db-query($sql,array(addslashes($name), $add));
```

then save that into your database, after doing this you will most likely need to use `stripslashes()` to remove the slashes from the data before you output it to the browser.

Comment: I tried your answer, but it doesnt work. it saves it as ganesh

Comment: @ganeshrj In your question can you please post the actual code your using?

Comment: $name=addslashes($name);
my query `$sql="insert into tablename (list_name,list_address) values(?,?)"

$res=this->db-query($sql,array($name,$add));`

is it correct usage what i am doing?

Comment: @ganeshrj Can you try what I just added to my answer?

Comment: i meant your previous answer.